# All directory permissions are listed as unwritable

Tags: joomla-3.4, permissions

I had a working website, but i had to move it to an other server. After i copied all files, directories and the database, everything seemed okay. But when I tried to install a new plugin, I got these errors:

```
Error
Archive does not exist


Warning
JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /var/www/xxxxxxxx/tmp/install_562f7fbf33ded

JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder. Path: /var/www/xxxxxxxx/tmp/install_562f7fbf33ded

JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /var/www/xxxxxxxx/tmp/install_562f7fbf33ded

JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file
```

I found [another post with a related solution](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7026/all-directories-listed-as-unwritable).

All permissions were listed as unwritable. But when i changed the owner and group of all the directories and files, nothing changed.

I know I should not do it, but I also tried to change some of the folders to 777 permission, but nothing changed. (it's a local test server)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's highly recommended to use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-backup.html) for site transfers. This (free) Joomla extension makes it extremely easy to transfer/backup your site, and helps avoid this kind of problems.

It looks like your **log** and **tmp** directories are not properly configured in your `configuration.php` file.

Open the file `configuration.php` in the root folder of your Joomla installation, and locate the following lines:

```
public $log_path = '/var/www/xxxxxxxx/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/var/www/xxxxxxxx/tmp';
```

Edit the path to match your new server environment.

You can also edit the paths from the admin area (System -> Global configuration). The path to your log folder can be set from the "System" tab, and your temp folder from the "Server" tab:

[image: Log folder setting]

[image: Temp folder setting]

**Make sure you remember to set your folder permission back to the [recommended values](https://docs.joomla.org/Verifying_permissions).**